# C#: How to access public member of a custom control from another custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I am working on windows application form. I have a CustomControl (say MasterControl) on which i put a split panel and now my MasterControl is split into three parts say:

- Pannel1
- Pannel2
- Pannel3

Now i develop three custom controls and put one in each of pannels e.g

- Pannel1 have CustomControl1
- Pannel2 have CustomControl2
- Pannel3 have CustomControl3

Now somewhere in CustomControl3 I need to access a **public member** of CustomControl1. For which i wrote the following code:

```
((MasterControl)this.Parent)._oCustomControl1.PublicMember = this.PublicMember;
```

The code above doen't work in my case. When this line of code is executed in debug mode then a message box appears and states that "There is no code available for current location"

Comment: Looks like you're running an out of date project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. I am positing here because it might help some one else.
The exact code is:

```
((MasterControl)this.Parent.Parent.Parent)._oCustomControl1.PublicMember = this.PublicMember;
```

Basically my coustomcontrol3 lies inside a split container panel, so when i wrote:
`this.Parent` then it points to Panel In which it is residing and if i wrote
`this.Parent.Parent` then it points to the spliter container in which above panel reside and if i wrote
`this.Parent.Parent.Parent` then it points to control in which this split container resides

I got the idea from "Farzin Zaker" answer, so thanks to him for his contribution

Answer (score 3):

It's a **really bad** design for your controls to depend on how are the arranged on the parent container.

e.g. inside your third control, you are quering the property of the first one by accessing it from the parent, and then it's child control by name.

Your code will break very easily, if it can be compiled at all - I think the problem you're having is the order of compilation: in order for your parent form to be compiled, it needs to have child user controls finished. On the other hand the user controls you created need to have finished form.

It would be far better to set whatever behaviour you're after from the container of those controls - for example, by reacting to events from the control, and setting appropriate stuff on appropriate other controls (there are other ways as well ofcourse - the point is in the direction and flow of information - who's setting and using what).

Comment: I totally agrees with you, but its an old code and i am only making some upgradations.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a split panel in your master control, you should go two levels up to find your master control:

```
((MasterControl)this.Parent.Parent)._oCustomControl1.PublicMember = this.PublicMember;
```